# Use quickfix for completion

Tags: autocompletion

Is there a way to use QuickFix as a source for auto-completion? Let me explain, my experiments with project-wide autocompletion did not end with any successful results and I tried every plugin imaginable

However *vim is autocompleting just fine from open files.

Quite often I use `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-L` to complete whole lines because I don't remember paths for importing libraries.

But to make it work I first need to search for a similar line and open the file containing it.

Is there a way to autocomplete from the QuickFix window where `:Ag` dumps the results?

Comment: Why not just dump results into buffer instead of quickfix window. Then you can autocomplete from that. What language you're using anyway? I thought about making infrastructure to generate parsers from AST with happy (haskell analog  of yacc).

Comment: Mostly Ruby and Javascript dumping into a buffer sounds reasonable. What would you suggest? vnew and then :r !ag ... ?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. There are deoplete ternjs and deoplete ruby plugins. Have you tried them? You probably haven't. Also there is ctags and gtags etc. Seems that they support JavaScript and ruby.